# Order by collection count using ICriteria & NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

Using the standard NHibernate example of Cats and Kittens, how would I use ICriteria to sort Cats based on Kitten count?  For example, I want to do something like:

```
ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat));
return crit.Order(Order.Asc("**Kittens.Count**"));
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In HQL you can do it like this:

```
select cat
from Eg.Cat cat
join cat.Kittens kitten
group by cat
order by count(kitten) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2401219

It's Java Hibernate but almost the same thing (Projection, AddOrder)

Comment: When I do projection & AddOrder

crit.SetProjection(Projections.Alias(Projections.Count("Kittens"), "kcnt")).SetResultTransformer(CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity).List();

The list has only 1 result -- an integer!

Comment: If you want the full entity plus a count(*), it's not easily doable... see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3537