# Order by relation count in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have a datastructure like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IList<Books> Books {get;set}
}
```

I have been struggeling with making it possible to sort the users by the count of bookmarks (one-to-many relation).

I have tried various approaches with both linq, criteria and queryover, but with no luck, and therefore hope one of you could help.

I am using paging, since I have quite a few users, so the solution needs to do the query on the SQL and not in memory on the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loadedUser = session.Query<User>()
    .Select(u => new { u, u.Books.Count })
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(anonym => anonym.Count)
    .Select(anonym => anonym.u);
```

or using HQL

```
select user
from User as user 
    left join user.Books as books
group by user
order by count(books)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this would be very slow, since you would do the sort in memory instead of on the SQL database.

Comment: @Dofs: if you're not paging, why do you think the DB will sort it faster? The DB will do it in memory too; it doesn't have a magic "sorting bucket" that exists outside the known universe...

Comment: Hi Diego, I am using paging, but didn't add it to the original question. It is now updated. I also tried your extension here: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/02/getting-row-count-with-future-linq.html, but I get the error: NoViableAltException(84@[]) and MismatchedTreeNodeException(70!=3) (Using NH 3.04)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon It's not that the DB has a more efficient sorting bucket (although it might if the relation is indexed), it's that to do it in the programs' memory means that every entry must be brought across the wire and mapped into an object before it can be ordered. That network and mapping time can be very significant.

Comment: @heneryville ...and? It's either sorted before sending, or after sending. You are just changing the place where that happens.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Ah, I was assuming paging/truncation/limiting, which you did mention.

Answer (score 0):

See : [Order by collection count using ICriteria & NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604572/order-by-collection-count-using-icriteria-nhibernate)

```
select u
from User u
join u.Books b
group by u
order by count(b) asc
```

Or using LINQ :

```
users.OrderBy(x => x.Books.Count);
```

Comment: I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but NHProfiler gives me a n+1 problem.

Comment: yes because all books will be fetched one time for each user. You should fetch them when you query for users.