# Linq to NHibernate and sub-object query

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've this Linq query:

```
var query = (from i in session.Query<Photo>()
                   where i.IsApproved == true
                   select i);

            if (topPhotoEnum.Equals(TimeModeEnum.Today))
                query = query.Where(x => x.UploadDate >= DateTime.Today 
                                       && x.UploadDate <= DateTime.Now);

 //return  query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Votes.Count).Take(number).ToList();

 return query.ToList()
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Votes.Count).Take(number).ToList();
```

the problem here is that I retrieve all data from database and then I call `OrderByDescending` and `Take` to filter data.

I'd prefer to let database filter data but seems Linq to NHibernate provider does not support `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Votes.Count)` because is a sub-collection operation.

> Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException
>
> NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException() +100
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate() +305
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String
>   collectionRole) +99
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2
>   replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole) +561
>
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2
>   replacements, Boolean shallow) +44
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode
>   ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +320
>
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String
>   queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +66
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +86
>
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +63
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String
>   expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow,
>   IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +53 
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) +249
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow) +185
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression) +158
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression,
>   IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery) +82
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +58
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +43
>   Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator() +120
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known limitation.

[Link to Issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2760?focusedCommentId=21267&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)

there are a lot of questions around what you want to achive

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844283/order-by-relation-count-in-nhibernate)

[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604572/order-by-collection-count-using-icriteria-nhibernate)

to sum up: use HQL, complex subqueries, sql or use latest NH

Comment: "...or use latest NH" what do you mean? Latest version supprt it?

Comment: AFAIK currently only in Trunk, no released version yet